# Coq: Defining a type class instance

Tags: class, types, coq

In the development below, I get a strange error when trying to define an instance of a single-method typeclass:

```
Universe ARG. Definition ARG := Type@{ARG}.
Universe ARG0. Definition ARG0 := Type@{ARG0}.
Universe ARG1. Definition ARG1 := Type@{ARG1}.
Universe ARG2. Definition ARG2 := Type@{ARG2}.
Constraint ARG<ARG0, ARG0<ARG1, ARG1<ARG2.

Inductive SR: ARG := Phy | Sen | Inf | Lim.
Parameter CA: Prop.
Parameter X: SR -> CA -> ARG -> ARG.
Parameter X': SR -> CA -> ARG -> ARG0.
Parameter XP: SR -> CA -> ARG -> ARG1.
Parameter XP': SR -> CA -> ARG -> ARG2.
Inductive tri:Set := one | two | three.

Definition iX' (t:tri): SR -> CA -> ARG -> ARG2 := match t with one => X' | two => XP | three => XP' end.
Parameter gk:> forall (b:SR)(d:CA)(c:ARG), X' b d c -> iX' one b d c.
Parameter gl:> forall (b:SR)(d:CA)(c:ARG), XP b d c -> iX' two b d c.
Parameter gm:> forall (b:SR)(d:CA)(c:ARG), XP' b d c -> iX' three b d c.

Definition iX'bsko {b:tri}{s:SR}{k:CA}{o:ARG} := iX' b s k o.
Parameter foo: forall {b:tri}{s:SR}{k:CA}{o:ARG}, iX' b s k o.
Fail Check foo: forall {b:tri}{s:SR}{k:CA}{o:ARG}, iX' b s k o. (*Why?*)
Check foo: iX'bsko.
Class CONN := p5 (x y z:ARG): x -> y -> z.
Instance cco: CONN := fun x y iX'bsko (_:x) (_:y) => foo.
(* Error: "foo" has type "iX' ?b@{y0:=x0; y1:=y0} ?s@{y0:=x0; y1:=y0} ?k@{y0:=x0; y1:=y0} ?o@{y0:=x0; y1:=y0}"
while it is expected to have type "iX'bsko". *)
```

The cause of the error seems to be that `foo` doesn't have type `iX'bsko`, while 2 lines above `foo: iX'bsko` type checked. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your comment `(*Why?*)`, the issue is that `foo` means `@foo _ _ _ _`.  The following succeds:

```
Check @foo: forall {b:tri}{s:SR}{k:CA}{o:ARG}, iX' b s k o.
```

To answer your question, you have shot yourself in the foot by shadowing the global `iX'bsko` with a local opaque variable.

If you change

```
Instance cco: CONN := fun x y iX'bsko (_:x) (_:y) => foo.
```

to

```
Instance cco: CONN := fun x y not_really_iX'bsko' (_:x) (_:y) => foo.
```

you get

```
Error:
In environment
x : ARG
y : ARG
not_really_iX'bsko : ARG
x0 : x
y0 : y
The term "foo" has type
 "iX' ?b@{y0:=x0; y1:=y0} ?s@{y0:=x0; y1:=y0} ?k@{y0:=x0; y1:=y0}
    ?o@{y0:=x0; y1:=y0}" while it is expected to have type
 "not_really_iX'bsko".
```

This is not surprising.  `CONN` is the type `forall x y z : Type@{ARG}, x -> y -> z`.  This type has no inhabitants:

```
Lemma no_conn : CONN -> False.
Proof. exact (fun cco => cco True True False I I). Qed.
```

Perhaps you meant to make `x`, `y`, and `z` arguments to `CONN` instead, writing something like this?

```
Class CONN (x y z:ARG) := p5 : x -> y -> z.
Instance cco x y : CONN x y iX'bsko := fun (_:x) (_:y) => foo.
```

Note that this fails with a much more clear-cut error message:

```
The term "iX'bsko" has type "ARG2" while it is expected to have type
"ARG" (universe inconsistency).
```

If you instead do

```
Class CONN (x y z:ARG2) := p5 : x -> y -> z.
Instance cco x y : CONN x y iX'bsko := fun (_:x) (_:y) => foo.
```

then you get

```
Error: Cannot infer the implicit parameter b of iX'bsko whose type is
"tri" in environment:
x, y : ARG2
```

Comment: Thanks. `Instance cco {b:tri}{s:SR}{k:CA}{o:ARG} x y: CONN x y (@iX'bsko b s k o) := fun (_:x)(_:y) => foo` works. Can I also get a working definition w/ `Class CONN := p5 (x y z:ARG2): x -> y -> z`? I suppose not -- just checking